# Convenient monitoring of database under Django

Tags: linux, mysql, django

I am developing a web app under **Linux** and use **Django** for its back-end along with **MySQL** database (via **DBeaver**). Everything is awesome, but I was not yet able to find a convenient way to monitor the behavior of Django ORM. I want to see which queries ultimately hit the database in a convenient way.

Here is what I mean by convenient.
I follow thru pages on the website in a normal way - just like an ordinary visitor. After I am done, I look at the sequence of queries that were hitting the database, as I was doing that. Ideally, I should be able to see it in real time (send request - see the query).

I know about the `.query` property of querysets, but I would need to write a whole separate module to interpret what to do with it. Plus, it would ruin my neat JSON objects that now only contain the actual website data.

I could also resort to Django logging or even MySQL logging tables. But is there a more dynamic way? After all, this does not seem like asking too much - just an ordinary request for debugging.

This is more of a workflow-organization question, rather than possible-code-implementation question, as I believe there should be db-agnostic tools for this.

Comment: This question might get more traction on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I asked this question on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/254585/convenient-monitoring-of-database-under-django). I will update here in case I get any results.